# Getting branch coverage for golang tests

Tags: go

Can someone suggest a way to me if we can get branch coverage for my golang tests? Let's say I have a golang code which looks like below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func HelloWorld(name string, printv int) string {
    if name == "tuk" || printv == 1 {
        fmt.Println("Hello tuk")
        return "Hello tuk"
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Who are you?")
        return "Who are you?"
    }
}
```

The corresponding test file looks like below:

```
package main

import "testing"

func TestHelloWorld(t *testing.T) {
    r := HelloWorld("tuk", 0)
    if r != "Hello tuk" {
        t.Error("Test Failed")
    }
}
```

If I execute the below test command, it is just giving me the statement coverage:

```
go test -coverprofile=cover.out .
ok      test    0.007s  coverage: 60.0% of statements
```

Is there a way I can get the branch coverage as well?

Comment: I think the -html report is a good way to find branch coverage.

Comment: @jsxqf Since the HTML report only has statement coverage, it cannot be used to extract the more detailed branch coverage from it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of Go 1.11 (November 2018), the generated machine code for the coverage [only covers each block of statements](https://golang.org/src/cmd/cover/cover.go#L377). It should be possible to take that code and adjust it to cover every branch of an expression.

It looks as if [the gobco project](https://github.com/junhwi/gobco) has done exactly this, although only for single files and not for whole packages (again, as of November 2018).

I [filed an issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/28888) to see whether branch coverage is considered to be worthwhile by the Go team. The decision is to keep the current code as simple as it is now, and that decision [had already been documented in the code itself](https://golang.org/src/cmd/cover/cover.go#L142).

In the end [I forked the gobco project](https://github.com/rillig/gobco) and added all the features I need.